# Chances of Being killed vs chances to be killed vs chances of killing

Tags: meaning

Here are four sentences with different sentence structures:

> what are the chances of being killed by a falling tree?
>
> what are the chances to be killed by a falling tree?
>
> what are the chances of killing by a falling tree?
>
> what are the chances of dying in a war ?

Are all these sentences grammatically correct and their meanings are the same ?

OR,

> What is the risk of being killed in a war?
>
> what is the risk to be killed in a war ?
>
> what is the risk of killing in a war?
>
> Is there a risk to be killed in a war ?

Are these four sentences grammatically correct and their meanings are same ?

Comment: Consult a dictionary for definitions of ***to kill*** and ***to die***.

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at [risk](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/risk) in a good dictionary, you will see some examples like this:

> 1) There's a high risk **of** another accident happening in this fog.
>   2) [ + (that) ] The risk (that) we might fail made us work twice as hard.
>   3) [ + -ing verb ] It's always a risk starting up a new business.
>   4) The company is quite a good risk (= safe to lend money to).
>   5) We want clean rivers and lakes, where you can swim without risk **to** your health.
>   6) It's a low/high-risk strategy (= one that is safe/not safe).

Your first and fourth sentences correspond to example one, and have the intended meaning. Your second, third, fifth, sixth and seventh sentences do not correspond to any of the examples. Sentences three and six might have some meaning, but it's not clear what it its.

Comment: Three and six would seem to mean `What are the chances of me killing someone by dropping a tree on them` (either vs missing them, or vs only injuring them) and `What are the chances of me killing someone in a war` (again, either vs not killing, or only injuring) respectively.  From the context, it seems that this meaning is quite the opposite of what the OP wants.

Comment: My dobt has been clear from both of these answers, No 1 and 2 have the same meaning in both set of examples, but why No 1 is more natural/common than No 2.

Comment: @yubrajsharma,  it's just a fact that we prefer to say "chances of -ing/ risk of -ing" rather than "chances to <infinitive>/risk to <infinitive>". There doesn't have to be a reason. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=chances+of+finding%2C+chances+to+find&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cchances%20of%20finding%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cchances%20to%20find%3B%2Cc0

Comment: If my questin hadn't been put on hold, I would accepte an answer. But, I don't know how to reopen it. Is here anyone to inform me about it?

Answer (score 2):

> what are the chances of being killed by a falling tree?

This is fine, although it's more common to use the singular,  "what is the **chance** of being ..."

> what are the chances to be killed by a falling tree?

Again, it's more natural to use the singular *chance*.  Also this is less common than "chance of being".

> what are the chances of killing by a falling tree?

The difference between this and the others is that the others are using the [*passive voice*](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/activepassive.html) of the verb "to kill".

> The tree kills me
>
> I am killed by the tree.

If you change from the passive to the active form of the verb, it changes who is doing the killing.  Now instead of the tree killing me, *I* am killing something.  Also, the "by" is not grammatical -- or rather, instead of saying *who* is killing, it indicates *where* the killing takes place.

So for fun you can say something like:

> What is the chance of (me) killing (something) by the falling tree?

It's an odd sentence, but it is grammatical.   The tree would have to be *falling* pretty slowly of course.

From your second set of examples:

> 1. What is the risk of being killed in a war?

is the most natural.  2 and 4 are fine.

As before, 3 has a completely different meaning, since now instead of you being *killed* in the war, you are the one doing the *killing* in the war.  It is unusual to say "risk of killing", since it's not obvious what *risk* you mean, but again, it is grammatical.

Comment: For your first one, it is more common to use singular, but make sure you replace the `are` with an `is`.

Comment: @cullub yes, agreed.  I should have made that clear in the answer.  Edited.

Comment: Thank you for answering me, very good answer but I'm curious to know why No 2 sentence is less comman or less natural to use to that of No 1 in both set of examples above ?

Comment: Unfortunately, this question has been put on hold. I don't know how to get it reopened . . . . .

Comment: Questions get put on hold, it's fine.  As for why #2 is more common than #1, all I can say is that it just is.   It's like hand gestures, each language has unique patterns.

Comment: Interesting... I would have said that "what are the chances.." was significantly more common than "what is the chance"... but ngram bears out your statement that "what is the chance" is more common. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=chances+of+finding%2Cchance+of+finding&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cchances%20of%20finding%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cchance%20of%20finding%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @JavaLatte Wow, I was right?  What are the chances of that!  :)

Comment: @JavaLatte Actually I routinely check ngram before I make assertions like this.  I've been spanked too many times on ELL by those who don't like unsupported claims.